# RxJs expand and delay operator not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm trying to use RxJs `expand` operator together with `delay` in order to reproduce a polling behavior to the server until the HTTP call returns success.

I use the `delay` operator as well because the HTTP call returns the following object:

```
{
    retryAfterInSeconds: 30,
    status: 'Running'
}
```

and I want to skip unnecessary calls if I know when I should check the status again.

So, I implemented the behavior as follows:

```
private pollExportStatus(entity: any): void {
    let waitingTime = 0;

    this.service
        .getStatus(entity)
        .pipe(
            untilDestroyed(this),
            expand((x: Status) => {
              waitingTime += x.retryAfterInSeconds;

              const shouldContinuePolling =
                waitingTime < 300 &&
                x.status !== StatusType.Succeeded &&
                x.status !== StatusType.Failed;

              if (!shouldContinuePolling) {
                return EMPTY;
              }

              return this.service
                 .getStatus(entity)
                 .pipe(delay(x.retryAfterInSeconds * 1000));
        }),
        last()
        )
        .subscribe((x: Status) => {
            if (waitingTime >= 300 || x.status !== StatusType.Succeeded
            ) {
              console.log('Failed');

              return;
            }

            console.log('Succeeded');
        });
}
```

Everything works as expected except one thing: even if I return the next call (inside expand) with a `delay`:

```
return this.service
  .getStatus(entity)
  .pipe(delay(x.retryAfterInSeconds * 1000));
```

the first call is not delayed and I don't understand why.

Finally, I found a solution that works as expected.

I replaced the `expand` return with the following one:

```
return timer(x.retryAfterInSeconds * 1000).pipe(
     concatMap(() => this.service.getStatus(entity))
);
```

but I want to understand why the first one is not working and the second one does.

*Note: the first behavior is working if I use a simple observable (created with `of` operator), but not with an HTTP call*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tobias provided a way of thinking from source emissions passing down through operators. 90% of the time it’s how I think too but it’s important to know what actually happens in terms of subscriptions and the creation of observables which go bottom up.

Let’s follow the stream bottom up.

You subscribe. But what are you subscribing to? The last piped operator `last()`. Internally this subscribes to a source observable and when that completes emits the last value from this source.

So what does `last()` subscribe to? I.e. what’s its source observable? The observable created by `expand(…)`.

Expand does a complicated dance but it’s essentially a recursive merge map where it emits the source emission plus any emissions from the observable resulting from the function provided applied to each emission. The key thing is that its source observable* whose first emission triggers the recursion is `this.service.getStatus(entity)`, and this has no delay. The second emission will be from `this.service.getStatus(entity).pipe(delay(30*1000))`. All delay does is delay emissions. The delay pipe subscribes internally to `this.service.getStatus(entity)` *immediately*. Thus you’ve just hit the server twice in a row.

* unaffected by `untilDestroyed(this)` which just subscribes to source and completes when this destroyed.

One point here is that `untilDestroyed(this)` should be last (EDIT: actually 2nd to last, since you want `last()` to run on completion). If this is at the top and there are delays in the middle then the stream may continue doing stuff after `this` is destroyed.

If you replace the first http with

```
of({
    retryAfterInSeconds: 30,
    status: 'Running'
})
```

then the first http request will be the one inside the expand with a delay.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are confused why the http request inside `expand` immediately fires instead of waiting for a second. The `delay` operator does *delay* the continuation of a pipe. But as soon as someone subscribes to an `Observable`, its execution will start from the top.

In this case, the subscription happens with the `.subscribe()` callback. The initial `this.service.getStatus()` call takes place and its result is passed to the `expand`. The execution continues to the next `this.service.getStatus(entity)` which will immediately fire the http request. *Afterwards*, there is a `delay`, which *delays* passing on the result of `getStatus` back to `expand`. The `delay` is essentially too far down the chain and happens too late.

The `timer` example works, because the `timer` only emits after waiting a second. Only then does the `getStatus` call happen.

Comment: *its execution will start from the top* This is not strictly true. It can be helpful to think of it like this but when you subscribe it’s the last pipe operator you’re subscribing to. It’s why `untilDestroyed(this)` should be last.

Comment: @AndrewAllen - I mean sure, you are subscribing to the last pipe operator. Can you elaborate on what you mean with *"not strictly true"* with the execution from the top? Thinking about it, there are exceptions like `shareReplay` where subscribing may access a cache instead of starting from the top. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: The reason I mention is because your way of thinking (following source emission) will confuse if you try using something like startWith and delay in the same stream. If you put startWith last it’ll fire immediately because that’s what you’ve subscribed to (I.e. bottom up following subscriptions). It fires regardless of whether a source emission occurred. Like I said thinking top down is helpful but not strictly true and can be helpful to think bottom up also.